# Blazor wasm client-server communication

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly

I'm developing an online game using Blazor WebAssembly and I'm facing a problem with client-server communication.

I decided to use SignalR (as it is already used on server-side Blazor) but I faced few issues.

I've got quite complicated object architecture- inheritances, nested objects, dictionaries, 2D arrays etc. I followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server) and simple messages like strings are sent as intended, but when I try to send my compicated objects with all the dictionaries and stuff, it doesn't work anymore. What I found is, that it uses JSON format to send messages (am I right?), which simply does not support nested objects, 2D arrays etc. (and I don't won't to parse all the objects into string or something...). However on server-side blazor, the communication works flawlessly even with complex data structures, because it uses websockets (again, is that correct?).
Is there a way to use this server-side blazor communication in Blazor WebAssembly?
Or what do you suggest as the best solution for client-server communication? (fast communication, nested objects support, dictionaries support etc...)
I've read about json, messagepacks, websockets.
Any help greatly appreciated ;)

Code on server hub:

```
public async Task OnLogin(string gameId)
{
    //gvars contains all information about game - list of players, items etc.
Gvars gvars = GetGameInfo();
Player player = CreateNewPlayer();
    await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveIdAndGameInfo", gvars, player.Id); 
}
```

Code on client:

```
public async Task Start()
{
    hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/myhub"))
        .Build();

    hubConnection.On<Gvars, int>("ReceiveIdAndGameInfo", (gv, id) =>
    {
        ReceiveNewId(gv, id);
    });

    await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    await hubConnection.SendAsync("OnLogin");
}

private void ReceiveNewId(Gvars gvars, int id)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.gvars = gvars;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Comment: JSON supports objects and arrays. Please show your code and sample data, and explain specifically what error/problem is occuring. We can't fix descriptions of code. Please provide a [mre] of the issue. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but please also provide a clear explanation of your specific issue, as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SIgnalR for a web assembly app, strikes me as a bit of a backward step.
SignalR is a javascript library and the app will have to write data over the JSinterop.

It's just what's needed for a server side blazor app but for a web assembly, it would be easier to write a C# class and use either the HttpClient class or ClientWebSocket class, which will do the same thing but inside the web assembly.